# `grep --line-number -C9`: no padding option? It moves lines when one and two digits results presented

Tags: grep

I am getting result like:

```
file-7-   xxxxxxxx
file-8-   xxxxxxxx
file-9-   xxxxxxxx
file-10-   xxxxxxxx
```

But I want, for example:

```
file -7-   xxxxxxxx
file -8-   xxxxxxxx
file -9-   xxxxxxxx
file-10-   xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no option to change that. I've thought about making one for [ack](https://beyondgrep.com) but I've never wanted it that bad.

Comment: @AndyLester site is unavailable

Comment: Ooops, typo, it's beyondgrep.com

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich, could you please do let us know if you are ok with other tools like: `awk` or any other please, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 do you know `awk` solution?